# MIddleman with HAML - Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal

Tags: templates, haml, middleman

I'm using middleman with the html5 boilerplate template.
Problem is, the default template is in erb and my other templates (which wrap or "inherit" the default one) are in haml.
I googled a bit and it seems middleman doesn't support nested templates that use different templating engines so I figured that if HAML supports regular HTML I can easily switch the base template to HAML like so:

For example this is **base_temlpate.haml**:

```
<head>...</head>
<body>

   = yield 

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

And this is temlpate.haml:

```
wrap_layout :base_layout do
  %div
    = yield
```

When i try to run this I get `Illegal nesting: nesting within plain text is illegal.`

This is my first time using HAML so maybe i'm not doing it right?

Comment: Is your project on github? if so can you please post the link, and I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have html tags in your haml file. Replace `<head>...</head>` with

```
%head
  = ...
```

and so on.

(Or you can use a HTML based template language (like `erb`) for your base file and haml for your partial.)